# How to get buttons of all forms on webpage using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, mechanize

I searched for answer before ask here but didn't get lucky enough. So here it goes, I am doing web scraping using python selenium. before choosing selenium I checked for mechanize, scrapy but I failed to execute some button clicks with them then I checked selenium it seems okay with some cons. I am saying all this because if I chose the wrong tool then please correct me before it is too late.

My question about selenium is how do I get all elements on webpage using xpath. eg: On webpage each webpage I got 10 forms and each of them has a button. So I want to get all the forms on web page to loop on them and click button one by one.

eg:

```
<form id="#F0">
    <input type="button" name="itens" value="Items" class="texField2" onClick="somefunction()"/>
</form>
<form id="#F0">
    <input type="button" name="itens" value="Items" class="texField2" onClick="somefunction()"/>
</form>
<form id="#F1">
    <input type="button" name="itens" value="Items" class="texField2" onClick="somefunction()"/>
</form>
<form id="#F2">
    <input type="button" name="itens" value="Items" class="texField2" onClick="somefunction()"/>
</form>
<form id="#F3">
    <input type="button" name="itens" value="Items" class="texField2" onClick="somefunction()"/>
</form>
<form id="#F4">
    <input type="button" name="itens" value="Items" class="texField2" onClick="somefunction()"/>
</form>
```

Another thing, What I am doing is I click on button on 1st form (it takes me to another page, I go back to history and click on 2nd button then go back to history and so on) it seems scraping would be slow. Is there any better way to do the same?

Thank you !!

Edit:

```
from selenium import webdriver
mydriver = webdriver.Firefox()

baseurl = """http://www.comprasnet.gov.br/consultalicitacoes/ConsLicitacao_Filtro.asp?numprp=&dt_publ_ini=24/02/2016&dt_publ_fim=10/03/2016&chkModalidade=1,2,3,20,5,99&chk_concor=31,32,41,42&chk_pregao=1,2,3,4&chk_rdc=1,2,3,4&optTpPesqMat=M&optTpPesqServ=S&chkTodos=-1&chk_concorTodos=-1&chk_pregaoTodos=-1&txtlstUf=&txtlstMunicipio=&txtlstUasg=&txtlstGrpMaterial=&txtlstClasMaterial=&txtlstMaterial=&txtlstGrpServico=&txtlstServico=&txtObjeto="""
mydriver.get(baseurl)
mydriver.find_element_by_id('ok').click()
buttons  = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//form//input[@type='button']")
for button in buttons:
    button.click()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get forms buttons by xpath with code below:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//form//input[@type='button']")
```

And iterate them via simple for loop:

```
for button in buttons:
    button.click()
```

Alternativelly you can use [find_elements_by_css_selector](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html#locating-elements) function to get elements:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='button']")
```

Comment: I tried that already didn't work for me. editing code to add my script it gives error 
for button in buttons:
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Comment: @StackUP does it required to use xpath ?

Comment: sorry, may be I didn't get you. do we have another way to get submit button on each form?

Comment: @StackUP Yes you can use `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('input[type=button]`)` function to get all buttons

Comment: @StackUP Also i've updated `find_element_by_xpath` to `find_elements_by_xpath` (replace element to elements).

Comment: Thank you @Andriy, css selector does the job. however I need to comeback to history to click on next :)

Comment: Tried, coming back but it gives error on click again without search element,
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Comment: @StackUP it's really depends on particular case how you can handle that situation ... for instance you can keep index of button you clicked on then grub buttons again, and click on button with next index if it exists, i think that such approach would help you ..

Comment: button index is preserved as it is running in for loop but browser stage changes on clicking first button and coming back to history is not same don't know why. Not working for me.

Comment: @StackUP so you have to fetch buttons by css selector again and click on next one like buttons[index].click